# Dimension of set of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is a 7x5 matrix with a rank equal to 3.

The formula is as follows: Dimension = Rank + Nullity

Is the dimension 5 because there are 5 columns or 5 because that is the smaller of the two.

For example if it were a 5x7 matrix would the dimension still be 5 or is it 7?

Comment: The number of columns is the the dimension.

Comment: Dimension is usually the number of your column vectors.

Comment: @Tunococ So 5x7 matrix has a dimension of 7

Comment: "dimension" in the formula you mention is the dimension of the source space when the matrix is viewed as a linear transformation. I usually wouldn't say a 5-by-7 matrix has dimension 7. Its domain has dimension 7, and its codomain has dimension 5, but the matrix itself has dimension ... 5-by-7 I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

OP says: *"The formula is as follows: Dimension = Rank + Nullity"*

The only way this makes sense is if *dimension* is the number of columns in $A$. This is because, number of columns = dimension of the row space + dimension of the null space.  Note that given an $m \times n$ matrix, $A$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$, the row space and null space are both subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^n$ and, $n = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{nullity}(A)$.